# Need to save/update child 500 or more rows in parent-child relationship with-in 10sec using Spring-Data-JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I need to save or update 500 or more item in postgres db within 10sec using spring-data-jpa. below are my domain and service class.

GroupingForm.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "GroupingForm")
public class GroupingForm implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "grouping_form_id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID groupingFormId;

    @Column(name = "grouping_form_name")
    private String groupingFormName;

    @Column(name = "vid")
    private String vid;

    @Column(name = "vendor_name")
    private String vendorName;

    @Column(name = "hovbu")
    private String hovbu;

    @Column(name = "fid")
    private String fid;

    @Column(name = "factory_name")
    private String factoryName;

    @Column(name = "item_count")
    private Integer itemCount;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Timestamp creationDate;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    private Timestamp modifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "product_engineer")
    private String productEngineer;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "sourcing_type")
    private String sourcingType;

    @Column(name = "total_comments")
    private Integer totalComments;

    @Column(name = "factory_name_chinese")
    private String factoryNameChinese;

    @Column(name = "grouping_form_type")
    private String groupingFormType;//to save as Product/transit/Product_transit

    @Column(name = "ref_id")
    private String refId;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupingForm", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ProductItemsMapping> productItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupingForm", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TransitItemsMapping> transitItems = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Column(name = "pdf_status")
    private String pdfStatus;
}
```

ProductItemsMapping.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProductItemsMapping")
public class ProductItemsMapping implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "product_item_id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID productItemId;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grouping_form_id")
    private GroupingForm groupingForm;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "dim_Item_ID",name = "item_id")
    private Item item;

    @Column(name ="item_relationship_id", insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private String itemRelationshipId;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_relationship_id",referencedColumnName = "dim_item_relationship_id")
    private VendorFactoryItem vendorFactoryItem;

    @Column(name = "edam_id")
    private String edamId;

    @Column(name = "model_number")
    private String modelNumber;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "material")
    private String material;

    @Column(name = "finishing_colour")
    private String finishingColour;

    @Column(name = "dimensions")
    private String dimensions;

    @Column(name = "product_net_weight")
    private String productNetWeight;

    @Column(name = "insertion_order")
    private Integer insertionOrder;

    @Column(name = "comments")
    private String comments;

    @Column(name = "item_unique_id")
    private String itemUniqueId;

}
```

TransitItemsMapping.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TransitItemsMapping")
public class TransitItemsMapping implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "transit_Item_id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID transitItemId;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grouping_form_id")
    private GroupingForm groupingForm;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "dim_Item_ID",name = "item_id")
    private Item item;

    @Column(name ="item_relationship_id", insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private String itemRelationshipId;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_relationship_id",referencedColumnName = "dim_item_relationship_id")
    private VendorFactoryItem vendorFactoryItem;

    @Column(name = "edam_id")
    private String edamId;

    @Column(name = "model_number")
    private String modelNumber;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "packaging_details")
    private String packagingDetails;

    @Column(name = "packaging_method")
    private String packagingMethod;

    @Column(name = "is_side_stack")
    private String isSideStack;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "dimensions")
    private String dimensions;

    @Column(name = "product_net_weight")
    private String productNetWeight;

    @Column(name = "plastic_bag_ind")
    private String plasticBagInd;

    @Column(name = "insertion_order")
    private Integer insertionOrder;

    @Column(name = "comments")
    private String comments;

    @Column(name = "item_unique_id")
    private String itemUniqueId;

    @Column(name = "itm_pak_qty")
    private Integer itemPackQuantity;
}
```

Item.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    //@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "dim_Item_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID dimItemId;

    //mdm columns start
    @Valid
    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemId itemId;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name="effective_date")
    private Timestamp effectiveDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="expiration_date")
    private Timestamp expirationDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="business_area_number")
    private Integer businessAreaNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="business_area_desc")
    private String businessAreaDesc;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="division_number")
    private Integer divisionNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="division_desc")
    private String divisionDesc;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="sub_division_number")
    private Integer subDivisionNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="sub_division_desc")
    private String subDivisionDesc;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="product_group_number")
    private Integer productGroupNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="product_group_desc")
    private String productGroupDesc;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="assortment")
    private Integer assortment;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="assortment_desc")
    private String assortmentDesc;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="status")
    private Integer status;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="status_desc")
    private String statusDesc;

    @Column(name = "origin_country")
    private String originCountry;

    @Column(name = "destination_country")
    private String destinationCountry;

    @Column(name = "is_private_brand")
    private String isPrivateBrand;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brandName;

    @Column(name = "item_weight")
    private Double itemWeight;

    @Column(name = "in_box_height")
    private Double inBoxHeight;

    @Column(name = "in_box_width")
    private Double inBoxWidth;

    @Column(name = "in_box_depth")
    private Double inBoxDepth;

    @Column(name = "primary_image")
    private String primaryImage;

    @Column(name = "component_materials")
    private String componentMaterials;

    @Column(name = "product_detail")
    private String productDetail;

    @Column(name = "finishing_color")
    private String finishingColor;

    @Column(name = "packaging_method")
    private String packagingMethod;

    @Column(name = "packaging_quantity")
    private Integer packagingQuantity;

    @Column(name = "out_box_depth")
    private Double outBoxDepth;

    @Column(name = "out_box_height")
    private Double outBoxHeight;

    @Column(name = "out_box_width")
    private Double outBoxWidth;

    @Column(name = "net_weight")
    private Double netWeight;

    @Column(name = "plastic_bag_ind")
    private String plasticBagInd;
    //mdm columns ends
    //Adhoc specific start
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="is_current")
    private Integer isCurrent;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="remark")
    private String remark;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="is_valid")
    private String isValid;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name="creation_date")
    private Timestamp creationDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name="last_modified_date")
    private Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "is_adhoc_item")
    private String isAdhocItem;
    //Adhoc specific ends

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item")
    private List<VendorFactoryItem> vendorFactoryItems;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item")
    private List<ProductItemsMapping> productItems = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item")
    private List<TransitItemsMapping> transitItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer itemNumber;
    
    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String itemRelationshipId;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String vendorId;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String retailer;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String fid;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String hovbu;

    @Column(name="sourcing_type")
    private String sourcingType;

    @Column(name = "itm_pak_qty")
    private Integer itemPackQuantity;

    @Column(name = "barcode")
    private String barcode;

    @Column(name = "item_type")
    private String itemType;

    @Column(name = "item_cube")
    private String itemCube;
}
```

VendorFactoryItem.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "vendorfactoryitem")
public class VendorFactoryItem implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private VendorFactoryItemId vendorFactoryItemId;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "dim_item_relationship_id")
    private String itemRelationshipId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "hovbu",updatable = false,insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "item_number",updatable = false,insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "retailer",updatable = false,insertable = false)
    })
    private Item item;

    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private String itemIdRel;

    @Column(name = "is_adhoc_rel")
    private String isAdHocRel;
    
    @Column(name = "dim_factory_import_id")
    private String dimFactoryImportId;
    
    @Column(name = "factory_short_name")
    private String factoryShortName;

    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private String companyId;
    
    @Column(name = "vendor_short_name")
    private String vendorShortName;
    
    @Column(name = "remark")
    private String remark;

    @Column(name = "is_valid")
    private String isValid;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdOn;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "effective_date")
    private Timestamp effectiveDate;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vendorFactoryItem")
    private List<ProductItemsMapping> productItems = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vendorFactoryItem")
    private List<TransitItemsMapping> transitItems = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

GroupingFormRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface GroupingFormRepository
    extends JpaRepository<GroupingForm, UUID>, GroupingFormRepositoryCustom {

}
```

GroupingFormService.java

```
@Transactional
    public GroupingFormDto saveGroupingFormV1(GroupingFormDto groupingFormDto) {
        //do the mapping DTO to DOMAIN..remove the code ..
            **GroupingForm groupingFormSaved = groupingFormRepository.save(groupingForm);**
            
    }
```

With in the GroupingForm object I am setting the transitItem and productItem to save or update. And also adding Item and VendorfactoryItems not for save or update. what are the best way I can optimize this save and update with in 10 sec while I am passing more than 500 productItem and 500 transitItem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does the process take with the naive approach? What SQL is getting executed? Where does most of the time gets spend?

Comment: In general the fastest/easiest approach is to side step JPA and use something like `JdbcTemplate` and directly execute the exact SQL steps you need. This way you can also skip the construction of DTOs and entities.

Comment: Hi @JensSchauder sorry for late reply. actually while I am doing update that time it's started running the select query for item and vendorfactoryItem. and there it's taking most of the time.

Comment: Go with a `JdbcTemplate`